# Linq to SQL Multiple Conditions Based On Array

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to use LINQ in C# to perform  a SQL query which selects multiple records based on a complex query.

I have a List of Person classes that have the following members that i want to search by:
First Name and City.

Normally in SQL I would iterate over this List and generate the following where statement

```
Where (Name="Name1" and City="City1") or (Name="Name2" and City="City2") or ...
```

I am wondering how I can achieve a similar result using LINQ.

I could do this using multiple queries but I want to use less queries due to the latency of the network and to let the database self optimize. The List will contain no more than 100 items at any time.

**EDIT**

As stated in the below comments the Person class was just an example to try and keep things simple. I will try and go into full detail and explain what I am trying to accomplish and see if you can help me or provide a better solution.

I have 2 database table of interest

- Components
- Placements

Components contains 8 fields plus an ComponentID. Every component should be unique.

Placements contains a list of fields plus a FK back to Components.  There will be several Placements referencing one Component record in the database.

In C# I want to add Placements to the database with one transaction using a DataContext.  I will be adding upto 1000 Placement rows to the database.  If the Component does not exist I will have to create it. If it does exist I need to get its ComponentID so that I can link the Placement to the Component.

I have recently tried the following code:
The placementGroup has several members of which only 8 are needed to verify uniqueness. It should be noted that the 8 members listed below are unique between all of the objects stored in the list.

```
List<DBProductionComponent> existingComponents = context.DBProductionComponents.Where(dbc => placementGroup.Any(p => 
            p.ComponentName == dbc.ComponentName &&
            p.LotNumber == dbc.LotNumber &&
            p.Manufacturer == dbc.Manufacturer &&
            p.Package == dbc.PackageName &&
            p.PartNumber == dbc.PartNumber &&
            p.Supplier == dbc.Supplier &&
            p.SupplierPartNumber == dbc.SupplierPartNumber &&
            p.Value == dbc.Value
            )).ToList();
```

But get the following error: "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of queries except the Contains operator.

Comment: Is there a reasonable bound to the list of parameters? Like a maximum of 3 of these, or is it input by an external system or user? It could end up writing a poor query. Is this Person class stored in the database too and referenced as a FK? If so, you could use `.Where(q => q.Person.Contains(listOfPeople))` than can compare by ID.

Comment: The Person class is stored in the database but is split over several tables. The Person class contains information about the person plus several other Lists of data obtained from different queries or application operations.  I am not sure how I can use Contains() on only a portion of the Person's Classes data that is not directly aligned with the database

Comment: Can you post your mapping model? That may present us more info to provide you with a better query. You can make LINQ write a query to do what you're asking, but it will probably not end up being very performant, depending on your usage, load, size of data, size of parameters, etc. The more info you can give us the better we can help.

Comment: Are you using LINQ-to-SQL, LINQ-to-Entity Framework, LINQ-to-NHibernate, etc? Different providers generate SQL queries differently.

Comment: I was using Person as an example instead of the large complicated dataset, but I can add the mapping model if you still need it.  Essentially I have 2 tables. 1 table contains unique components (with 7 fields) the other table contains placement records.  Each placement record should refer to a component via a FK. I am adding up to 1000 placement records in a transaction which can consist of 1 to 100 unique components.  No all components exist in the database so if they are not present I would add them within the same transaction.